# Understanding the chi2gof function in matlab

Tags: matlab, chi-squared

I'm trying to understand how to use the chi2gof function in matlab with a very simple test. Let's assume that I toss a coin 190 times and get 94 heads and 96 tails. The null hypothesis should be that i get 95h, 95t. As far as I understand the documentation, I should be able to test the hypothesis by running

`[h,p,stats] = chi2gof([94,96], 'expected', [95,95])`

However, this returns h = 1, which supposedly means that null hypothesis is rejected, which makes no sense. Another pecular thing is that the `O` parameter in `stats` returns as `O: [0 2]` - but shouldn't this be my input (`[94,96]`)? What am I doing wrong?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This post can help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1819440/356329

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing the cumulative outcome of your coin tosses to `chi2gof`. The goodness-of-fit test must be performed on the full sample. From the official documentation (reference [here](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/chi2gof.html)):

- `x` = sample data for the hypothesis test, specified as a vector (*the wrong part of your code*)
- `Expected` = expected counts for each bin (*the correct part of your code*)

Let's make an example using the correct variables:

```
ct = randsample([0 1],190,true,[0.49 0.51]);
[h,p,stats] = chi2gof(ct,'Expected',[95 95]);
```

The returned value of `h` is `0`, which is absolutely correct.

Now, let's make an example that is supposed to fail:

```
ct = randsample([0 1],190,true,[0.05 0.95]);
[h,p,stats] = chi2gof(ct,'Expected',[95 95]);
```

As you can see, `h` returned from this second test will be equal to `1`.

On a final note, don't forget to take a look at the second output argument, which is the `p-value` of the test and is an important element to evaluate the significance of the result.